# How to separate environments of a project in docker and docker-compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a couple of basic conceptual question regarding the **environments of a webapp**.

I am trying to build a dockerized Rails app, having: test, development, staging and production.

1. My first question is, should the Dockerfile and docker-compose be the same for every environment?

The only thing that would change then would be that when I want to do the testing I pass the RAILS_ENV=test when creating a container, when I want to do the development I pass RAILS_ENV=development and so on.

Would this be the correct idea behind it?
Or can they be different (in my case I am building `nginx` on production together with `app` and `db` but I have just a simple setup with only the `app` and `db` for testing and development)

2. My second question is, when I pass the RAILS_ENV=test for example, should I do it on the Dockerfile (conditionally pass a different environment when building the image):

```
# Set environment
ARG BUILD_DEVELOPMENT
# if --build-arg BUILD_DEVELOPMENT=1, set RAILS_ENV to 'development' or set to null otherwise.
ENV RAILS_ENV=${BUILD_DEVELOPMENT:+development}
# if RAILS_ENV is null, set it to 'production' (or leave as is otherwise).
ENV RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-production}
```

Or keep the same image and pass the RAILS_ENV when doing the `docker-compose` ? :

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml run rake db:create db:migrate  RAILS_ENV=production
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should the `Dockerfile` be the same for every environment?

Yes.  Build a single image and reuse it in all environments.  Do not use Dockerfile `ARG` to pass in "is it production", or host names, or host-specific user IDs.  Especially you should use an identical environment in your pre-production and production environments to avoid deploying an untested image.

> Should `docker-compose.yml` be the same for every environment?

This is the main place you have to control deploy-time options like, for example, where your database is located, or what level of logs should be output.  So it makes sense to have a separate Compose file per environment.

Compose supports [multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).  You can use `docker-compose -f ...` multiple times to specify specific Compose files to use; or if you do not have that option then Compose will read both a `docker-compose.yml` and a `docker-compose.override.yml`.  So you might have a base `docker-compose.yml` file that names the images to use

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    image: registry.example.com/app:${APP_TAG:-latest}
```

In the question you suggest a `docker-compose.prod.yml`.  That can set `$RAILS_ENV` and point at your production database:

```yaml
# docker-compose.prod.yml
services:
  app:
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=production
      - DB_HOST=db.example.com
      - DB_USERNAME=...
    # (but don't repeat image:)
```

You could separately have a `docker-compose.dev.yml` that launched a local database, and had instructions on how to build the image:

```yaml
# docker-compose.dev.yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=development
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_USERNAME=db
      - DB_PASSWORD=passw0rd
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=db
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=passw0rd
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

If you use the `docker-compose -f` option, you need to always mention *both* files you're using

```sh
docker-compose \
  -f docker-compose.yml \
  -f docker-compose.dev.yml \
  run app \
  rake db:migrate
```

You could also symlink `docker-compose.override.yml` to point at an environment-specific file, and then Compose would be able to find it by default.

```sh
ln -sf docker-compose.test.yml docker-compose.override.yml
docker-compose run app rspec
```

Comment: Thank you! In your examples, I would understand if I did `docker-compose \
  -f docker-compose.yml \
  -f docker-compose.prod.yml \
  run app \
  rake db:migrate` since `docker-compose.prod.yml` doesn't build an image but `docker-compose.yml` does it. But for doing `docker-compose \
  -f docker-compose.yml \
  -f docker-compose.dev.yml \
  run app \
  rake db:migrate` since both `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.dev.yml` are building the image, what would the difference be? Or does the `docker-compose.dev.yml` way of building the image overrides the `docker-compose.yml` one?

Comment: The setup I show here doesn't build the image in the main `docker-compose.yml` at all, nor does it build it in the `docker-compose.prod.yml` file.  In production you'd run an image pulled from a registry at a known tag, and not separately copy the application source code to the target system.

Comment: Sorry I meant, for the `dev` one, we are doing `docker-compose \
  -f docker-compose.yml \
  -f docker-compose.dev.yml \
  run app \
  rake db:migrate`. In the `docker-compose.yml` we pull the image from `DockerHub` but then again in the `docker-compose.dev.yml` we are building it. Is there a reason for that? Or maybe the building image command in the `docker-compose.dev.yml` just overwrites the pull we do on `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: When you have both files together, you have the settings from both, so both `image:` and `build:`.  This combination tells Compose the image name to use when you `docker-compose build` (and therefore when you `docker-compose push` it knows where to go).